# If $A$ is invertible, show that span{$u_{1}, u_{2}, . . . , u_{k}$} = span{$v_{1}, v_{2}, . . . , v_{k}$}

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $u_{1}, u_{2}, . . . , u_{k}$ and $v_{1}, v_{2}, . . . , v_{k}$ be
>    vectors in $ℝ^n$ such that $$ v_{j} = a_{1j}u_{1} + a_{2j}u_{2} + · ·
>  · + a_{kj}u_{k}$$ for $j = 1, 2, . . . , k $, where $a'_{ij}$ are real
>    numbers.
>
> Let A be $(a_{ij})_{k × k}$
>
> If $A$ is invertible, show that span{$u_{1}, u_{2}, . . . , u_{k}$} =
>    span{$v_{1}, v_{2}, . . . , v_{k}$}

I know that if we want to prove $A=B$, it is necessary to show that $A⊆B$ and $B⊆A$. This could goes through a series of row operations using Gauss-Jordan Elimination, for example.

Now, how does $A$ being invertible affects this proving and what does this "$ v_{j} = a_{1j}u_{1} + a_{2j}u_{2} + · ·
 · + a_{kj}u_{k}$" actually means?

Thankyou.

Comment: Can you also write the $u_i's$ as linear combinations of the $v_j's$? Try writing the equations in matrix form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each $v_j$ can be written as linear combination of the $u_j$'s so every vector in $\text{span} \{ v_1, \ldots, v_k \}$ can be represented as linear combination of $u_j$'s, which follows $\text{span} \{ v_1, \ldots, v_k \} \subseteq \text{span} \{ u_1, \ldots, u_k \}$.

Thus, it suffices to prove $\text{span} \{ u_1, \ldots, u_k \} \subseteq \text{span} \{ v_1, \ldots, v_k \}$, i.e. each $u_i$ can be represented as linear combination of the $v_i$'s. Indeed:

$A$ is invertible means there exists $k \times k$ matrix $A^{-1}$ so $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Let $U=(u_1, \ldots, u_k)^T$ and $V=(v_1, \ldots, v_k)^T$ (here $A^T$ means transpose of matrix $A$) then from the given condition, we have $A^TU=V$ so $(A^T)^{-1}A^TU=(A^T)^{-1}V$ or $U=(A^T)^{-1}V$. This shows that each $u_i$ can be represented as linear combination of the $v_i$'s.

**Explanation:**

I chose $A^T$ because of matrix multiplication. Only $A^TU=V$ but $AU \ne V$.

Indeed, if $A=(a_{i,j})_{k \times k}$ then $$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{21} & \dots  & a_{k1} \\
    a_{12} & a_{22} & \dots  & a_{2k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{1k} & x_{2k} & \dots  & a_{kk}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence, from [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) (note that $u_i,v_i$ is a row vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so $U,V$ are $k \times k$ matrices):
$$A^TU=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{21} & \dots  & a_{k1} \\
    a_{12} & a_{22} & \dots  & a_{2k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{1k} & x_{2k} & \dots  & a_{kk}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    u_1\\u_2\\ \ldots \\ u_k
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11}u_1+a_{21}u_2+\ldots+a_{k1}u_k \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{1k}u_1+a_{2k}u_2+ \ldots +a_{kk}u_k
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1\\v_2\\ \ldots \\ v_k
\end{pmatrix}=V.$$
Similarly, from $U=(A^T)^{-1}V$ (for simplicity, $U=BV$) you can find that each $u_i$ can be represented as linear combination of $v_j$'s.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed explanation. I have a few questions: Why is there a need to use $A^T$ and how does $U = (A^T)^-1 V$ shows that each $u_{i}$ can be represented as linear combination of the $v_{i}$? Thanks again.

Comment: @idolo I edited my explanation to answer your question. $A^T$ is used to have correct $A^TU=V$ according to matrix multiplication and notation of matrix $(a_{i,j})_{k \times k}$. Say, if you change the original problem to $v_{j} = a_{j1}u_{1} + a_{j2}u_{2} + · ·
 · + a_{jk}u_{k}$ then it will be $AU=V$ instead of $A^TU=V$.